# Is Taras Shevchenko's poetry collection really called "Kobzar" in Ukraine too?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, andriy-lyubka, carbide, taras-shevchenko

*Carbide* refers to one of Tys's college classmates "holding a copy of *Kobzar*", which was a collection of Taras Shevchenko poetry. There's also a book called *The Complete Kobzar* in English. Is this basically the same collection? Is the name the same in both English and Ukrainian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

https://a.co/d/8xHMLC9 is an Amazon link to the Ukranian edition, the title in Ukranian is "КОБЗАР: Збірка поетичних творів"  (Kobzar: collection of poetic works)

Kobzar is a Ukranian word that means bard basically.

> Literally, kobzar in Ukrainian means a bard, although not a regular one, but rather the one who along with singing plays on a musical instrument, kobza. Kobza is roughly similar to a lute.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobzar_(poetry_collection)